# Allow temporary pinning or hiding of answers in a given thread

Tags: feature-request, answers, usability, stack-exchange

I would like the ability to pin an interesting answer on screen when I go to look at more answers (or to hide the uninteresting answers). Granted, I could open multiple browser windows or tabs but this isn't so convenient for comparing two answers.

This would be useful when say comparing opposing views or suggestions, or creating a reference sheet before going away to try them and see what works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt the developers want to spend time implementing features already offered by both the browser and the operating system.

Comment: Very probably but don't ask, don't get

Comment: @Jeff: That is certainly true.